# How can I bind to a form property in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a directive to show validation messages for a form field in Angular.  Roughly, it looks like this:

```
<form name="someForm">
    <div>
       <input name="someField" type="text" ng-required="true" />
       <show-messages form-property="someForm.someField">
       </show-messages>
    </div>
</form>
```

My problem occurs when I attempt to construct the field name.

```
<form name="someForm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input name="{{ 'someField' + item.id}}" type="text" ng-required="true" />
        <show-messages form-property="????">
        </show-messages>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried every combination of binding statements I can think including:
"someForm[someField + item.id]"
"someForm[{{ 'someField' + item.id }}]"
"{{ 'someForm.someField' + item.id }}"
...

All of these result in parsing errors generally looking like:

[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column ... of the expression [someForm[{{ someField + $index }}]] ....

Hopefully this is a small error on my part and somebody can point me to the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have place hardcoded fieldname in `'`(single quote) to represent it as string & then concatenate it with `item.id` like `someForm['someField' + item.id]`

```
<show-messages form-property="someForm['someField' + item.id]"></show-messages>
```

By doing above thing it will fetch `someField1` field value from `someForm` object.